# v-validate not working on dynamic generated fields vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I'm trying to validate dynamic fields using v-validate but it is working for fields that are not dynamic but the same code does not work for dynamic generated fields:

```
 <div v-if="condition=='true'> 
         <input :name="user.name" class="form-control input-md" type="text" :v-model="user.user_value" :v-validate="'required'" :class="['form-control', {'is-invalid': errors.has(user.name)}]"/>
                                <div :v-show="errors.has(user.name)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ errors.first(user.name) }}
                                </div>
    </div>


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: {},
      form: new Form({
        contact: "",
      }),
    };
  },
  methods: {
 getvalues() {

  axios.get(APP_URL + `/api/get-values?Id=${id}`, { headers: header })
        .then((response) => {

  for (var i = 0;i < response.data.list[0].student.length; i++) {
        var id = response.data.list[0].student[i].id;
        var name = response.data.list[0].student[i].name;
  }



    this.form.user.push({
                id: id,
                name: name,
                user_value: "",
              });

 }
   },
```

Comment: You must use `v-if`
, as it is not rendered in html.

Comment: @Danizavtz: I have a outer div there i have used v-if, updated my code in the question, Please check, my main issue is of validating dynamic fields.

Comment: which version of v-validate are you using?

Comment: @Danizavtz look like, he use `v2.*.*`

Comment: you are binding the :name and :v-model. with different fields.

Comment: I'm using vee validate v2

Comment: @Danizavtz: i am getting text input value in user.user_value as these fields are dynamic .

Comment: Can you post a complete .vue file, i think it is related to your component data function.

Comment: @Danizavtz: actually my code is too large to post i have added some more code, it will give you an idea what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

you should upgrade to vee-validate v3 it's better to use and small

anyway I think what you need to do is add a key attribute to the input

look for this example from vee-validate v2:

```
<template v-if="loginType === 'username'">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input placeholder="Enter your username" key="username-input">
</template>
```

[See docs for more details](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/conditional-and-looping-inputs.html#handling-v-if)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Please check i have added more detail to the question above, Actually i want to validate the dynamic fields but vee-validate is not working for dynamic fields i think, i can submit the form without value

Comment: @user3653474 I checked the new code
you didn't add a key attribute to the input field, please add it then try if it works and tells me the result

Comment: I am getting it inside user, and in for loop i am rendering this input field, my field are rendered properly only issue is of validating dynamic input fields